# compile error with tf transformation

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,

I have written some codes as below:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <tf/transform_broadcaster.h>
#include <nav_msgs/Odometry.h>
int main(int argc,char ** argv){
    ros::init(argc,argv,"odometry_publisher");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::Publisher pubOdom= n.advertise<nav_msgs::Odometry>("odom",50);
    tf::TransformBroadcaster odomBroadcaster;
    //some other codes
    ros::Rate r(10);
    while(n.ok()){
        //some other codes
        r.sleep();
    }
    //
    return 0;
}
```

and put

```
rosbuild_add_executable(OdomOFPS1_X64 src/OdomOFPS1.cpp)
```

in the end of the "CMakeLists.txt" file.

There is an error when compile:

```
OdomOFPS1.cpp.o: In function `main':
src/OdomOFPS1.cpp:22: undefined reference to `tf::TransformBroadcaster::TransformBroadcaster()'
src/OdomOFPS1.cpp:127: undefined reference to `tf::TransformBroadcaster::sendTransform(geometry_msgs::TransformStamped_<std::allocator<void> > const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It seems like a link error,the compiler could not find the "tf::TransformBroadcaster" class.Should I put the source code of the tf package in my project and compile them together or solve this problem by some other way?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214085/compile-error-with-tf--transformation/) by [redskydeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/22936/redskydeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 118 on 2015-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to link the executable against the tf libraries which are installed on your system. There's documentation of how to do that for rosbuild [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbuild/CMakeLists/Examples#Linking_against_libraries_built_by_other_ROS_packages)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [redskydeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/22936/redskydeng/) on 2015-07-20**:
Thanks,tfoote.

I have solved this problem by adding "target_link_libraries(OdomOFPS1_R32 tf)" in the "CMakeLists.txt" file. It seems like that the compiler linked the libtf.so shared object file in the lib directory.

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2015-07-20**:
Isn't it enough to add dependency to `tf` package in `manifest.xml`? As I understand `rosbuild_init()` in `CMakeLists.txt` will take care of these dependencies, when `rosbuild_add_executable()` is used.

**Comment by [redskydeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/22936/redskydeng/) on 2015-07-21**:
Hi,Boris,

Should I add   into the **manifest.xml**?
I will try,thank you very much!

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2015-07-24**:
I made a package from scratch and it did work with just a dependency, so it should be enough. Anyway, I guess you have tried it already :)

**Comment by [redskydeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/22936/redskydeng/) on 2015-07-25**:
Boris,
YES,It works.Thanks a lot!:D